# The "Save email setting" button is unclickable when choosing the same option from the dropdown select in profile preferences

Tags: bug, profile-page

Under the **"Preferences"** link option in the **"Edit Profile & Settings"** tab in Stack Overflow, there is an option to **"Email me my unread inbox messages"** with a dropdown select with 3 different options.

- every 3 hours
- daily
- weekly

The checkbox for it is unchecked by default and then automatically checked when simply "looking" at what the dropdown options are, without changing what the default selection is. In my case it was **"daily"**.

The **"Save email setting"** button is still grayed out and unclickable even if I choose **"daily"** from the dropdown select again.

I have to uncheck the checkbox next to **"Email me my unread inbox messages"**, then check it back in order for the button to be made clickable in order to have **"daily"** being the option I chose.

The button should be made clickable if I choose that same option again. One shouldn't have to uncheck it, then check it again.

I see this as a form of bug; or is this by design?

I included a short animated `.gif`:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies within this block of code:

```
$("#email-freq").val(3).on("click focus", function() { $("#email-enable").prop("checked", true); });
$("#email-notify").keyup(enableSave);
$("#email-enable, #email-freq, #optOutEmail, #optInNewFeatures, #optInTipsAndRecommendations").change(enableSave);
```

On line three of the block, jQuery is used to select elements matching a number of selectors, on of those being `#email-enable`. The code then assigns a "change" event listener to those elements.

Before that line one defines the mechanism for the drop down menu enabling the checkbox as setting the 'checked' attribute of the checkbox to checked. Makes sense right? If we set the checkbox to checked, the status of the checkbox changes. Wrong.

Check out the following quote from [Web/Events/change](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change) on MDN:

> The change event is fired for `<input>`, `<select>`, and `<textarea>` elements when a change to the element's value is committed by the user. Unlike the input event, the change event is not necessarily fired for each change to an element's value.
>
> ...
>
> Depending on the kind of form element being changed and the way the
>   user interacts with the element, the change event fires at a different
>   moment:
>
> - When the element is activated (by clicking or using the keyboard) for
>     `<input type="radio">` and `<input type="checkbox">`;
> - When the user
>     commits the change explicitly (e.g. by selecting a value from a
>     `<select>`'s dropdown with a mouse click, by selecting a date from a
>     date picker for `<input type="date">`, by selecting a file in the file
>     picker for `<input type="file">`, etc.);
> - When the element loses focus
>     after its value was changed, but not commited (e.g. after editing the
>     value of `<textarea>` or `<input type="text">`).

From that quote we find out that it isn't as cut and dry as you might think, and in fact it turns out that changing the `checked` attribute of a checkbox *does not* trigger a change event, even though the state of the checkbox has changed.

This is demonstrated in the following example:

```js
const i = document.querySelector('input'), b = document.querySelector('button'); 
i.addEventListener('change', () => console.log('changed'), false);
b.addEventListener('click', () => i.checked = true, false);
```

```html
<input type="checkbox">
<button>click</button>
```

However, you can just check the current state, and trigger a click event (in turn causing the state to change *and* trigger a change event) if the checkbox is not currently checked.

```js
const i = document.querySelector('input'), b = document.querySelector('button'); 
i.addEventListener('change', () => console.log('changed'), false);
b.addEventListener('click', () => !i.checked && i.click(), false);
```

```html
<input type="checkbox">
<button>click</button>
```

Comment: I see. I take it that this most likely won't be part of the core design to implement that, had I made it a feature request, correct?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I would classify this as a bug. It should work as expected, and the fact that it doesn't is caused by a common misconception.

Comment: Thanks. I'm a bit puzzled as to why a tech/mod hasn't said anything about my question though, thoughts? If it's a bug, it should be (theoretically) fixed, wouldn't you agree?

Comment: Oh for sure, which i why I went out of my way to diagnose the problem and prescribe a fix. The fact that a dev hasnt gotten to it yet just shows that there aren't enough devs / they're all busy doing other things right now.

Comment: I wonder if I were to add the feature request tag if that would make a difference.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I doubt it. If it's tagged with [tag:bug] then a dev has seen it and it will be worked on eventually.

Comment: Ah ok. Well, time will tell I guess, thanks *cheers*